# SQL script in R containing double quotes "

Tags: r, oracle

I am trying to run a query from R to an Oracle DB. Trouble is, that the string doesn't like the double quotes ". For example, I'd like to run the query:

```
 select T.* from xyz.table1 T where T."ID"='123'
```

In R this would work like this:

```
 sql<-"select T.* from xyz.table1 T where T."ID"='123'"
```

R returns an Error, saying:

> ```
>  Error: unexpected symbol in sql<-"select T.* from xyz.table1 T where T."
> ```

**Note:** We need to use `"` around *ID*, as we want to force case-sensitivity, so that it doesn't match columns like: *id*, *Id*.

Comment: If your field name is `ID` (as opposed to `Id` or `id`) you can safely remove the double-quotes as they're not needed. All names in Oracle default to UPPER CASE. I also strongly recommend you don't create case-sensitive names - you're just asking for trouble by doing so, and your code will be an incredible mess that is at best difficult to understand. Best of luck.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a backslash `\` to escape the double quotes.

The command you need is:

```
sql <- "select T.* from xyz.table1 T where T.\"ID\"='123'"
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. It seems tha the problem is not with "" but with quotes in general. For example:
"select T.* from xyz.table1 T where T.\"ID\"='123'"     doesn't work
"select count(*) from xyz.table1 T"     works

Comment: @Iztok I think you need to be a  little more specific on the problem. The solution I have proposed fixes the error that you talk about in your question. If you have another error further along in your code, you should either edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: Sorry, initially I thought the quotes were the issue. When I run the query such as select T.* from xyz.table1 where T."ID" ='123', I get the following error:

Error: Database driver code: HYC00 
Database server code: 3 
Database driver message: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]Optional feature not implemented. 

Sorry for not knowing the topic upfront. I promise I will update the topic after the solution is found! Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: I figured out the issue: I was using Select *, there was a column with a RAW datatype, a type not handled by the RDBMS. The column contains binary data.
Thanks for the support!